# Django / mysqlclient looking for missing `libmysqlclient.18.dylib` file

Tags: python, mysql, django

I've setup a Django (1.8.18) environment using virtualenv (Python 2.7.10) and also installed MariaDB (10.2.6) on my Mac via homebrew. Django is setup to use MySQL through the `settings.py` file and also I've installed mysqlclient.

When I `runserver` I get a error saying:

`Error loading MySQLdb module: dlopen(/Users/wolfie/Code/django.thingy/.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/mariadb/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib`

I've had a look in that `/usr/local/opt/mariadb/lib/` folder and all I see close to that is

`libmariadb.3.dylib`

`libmariadb.dylib -> libmariadb.3.dylib`

Is there any reason why Django/mysqlclient is looking for for the wrong file or is it MariaDB is missing a file it should have?

Comment: you dont need mariadb library, unistall it and only keep mysqlclient

Comment: I've not personally installed the MariaDB library, only the package.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same issue. Once you activate your virtualenv, try the following:

```
env "CFLAGS=-I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" pip install -U --force-reinstall mysql-python --no-cache-dir --no-binary mysql-python
```